# MySQL Getting Data from SQL Query (phpmyAdmin)

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

So I figured out (got some help from this site too) how to insert a data into my query, but now I go on another tab on my C# tool at visual express 2008 where there is a textBox5 and I want all of the data to show up there(textBox5) after I click on the Update Button(button3). How Will I be able to do this? Here is the code at pastebin (please alter it yourself and re-upload it at pastebin.com and send me the link, many thanks!):  http://pastebin.com/g975HB1r

Answer (score 0):

Make a string to parse the data you want to display and set the textbox.text property to this string.

Also, change the textbox5_textchanged, because you will clear it, after the updating.

EDIT :
Added the suggested corrections on pasteBin. You can extend it, by using also the other columns.

http://pastebin.com/r0xEjKWj

Comment: Ops my bad, no I wont be clearing it.. I want the updates to show there.

Comment: What exactly do you want to display in this textbox?

Comment: Try something like this :
     textBox5.text = reader["ID"]

Do it in the while(reader.read) section

Comment: Anyone of you have teamviewer? You could come in my PC and fix it in 2 secs I'll vote for you please. It's really simple but I dont know exactly how to start it.